# How to get Selenium 3.0.1 to work on a Mac with IntelliJ

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I am using a Mac as well as IntelliJ. I am trying to update Selenium from 2.53 as the website I am testing has functions that no longer work with older versions of Firefox (version 46). I am trying to update to Version 49 of Firefox. I am trying to update to Selenium 3.0.1 from 2.53.

I have downloaded the 0.11.1 Geckodriver and named it to `geckodriver`. I have included:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/jwhitmore/Downloads/WebDrivers/firefox/geckodriver");.
```

I have set the folder geckodriver is in in the PATH. No matter what I do I cannot seem to get selenium webdriver 3.0.1 to work in IntelliJ.

```
public class MultiSelect {

    WebDriver driver;
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    @Before
    public void login() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/jwhitmore/Downloads/WebDrivers/firefox/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

        @After
    public void close() {
        driver.close();
    }

    public void loginTest() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://192.168.1.23:8080");
        driver.findElement(By.id("name-inputEl")).sendKeys("user");
        driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1009-inputEl")).sendKeys("pass" + Keys.ENTER);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/a[5]/span/span/span[2]")).click();
    }
}
```

I still get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
at com.compusoft.synoptixServer.Scheduler.MultiSelect.<init>(MultiSelect.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I have been wondering if this is a syntax issue with Mac?
Please any suggestions would be helpful. Let me know if there is any additional information you need.

Comment: try using "/Users/jwhitmore/Downloads/WebDrivers/firefox/" this path

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid not having permission to access into a Download folder on your computer, you can add the geckodriver executable into your project. I usually do the following:

```
/******** The driver selected is Local: Firefox  ********/      
         if ("FIREFOX".equalsIgnoreCase(browser)) {
             if("WINDOWS".equalsIgnoreCase(os)){
                 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", resourceFolder+os+"/geckodriver.exe");    
             }
             else{
                 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", resourceFolder+os+"/geckodriver");    
             }
             driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
}
```

I usually have a WebDriverFactory in order to open the instance on the OS you choose. I save all the executable files (geckodriver, chromedriver..) in the resourceFolder of my project.

Also, remember (on MacOSX) to give executable permission into the geckodriver file:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

If you want to see an example, you can see my repository here: https://github.com/estefafdez/selenium-cucumber/blob/master/src/main/java/com/selenium/configure/environment/WebDriverFactory.java

I hope it works for you now!

Answer (score 0):

You can let Webdriver try to locate the geckodriver executable from the system PATH but you will need to add the directory containing the executable to the system path.

This can be done from the shell with the following command:

- `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver`

Then in @before:

- `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver");`
- `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Usage.html

Answer (score -1):

try adding `.exe` to geckodriver. it may work - you also can move the driver somewhere specific and reference it explicitly:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/exeter/D‌​ownloads/geckodriver‌​");
DesiredCapabiliti‌​es capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I figured that Mac couldn't use .exe's?

In any case I add the .exe and now it just throws a NullPointerException. Not sure if that moves me in the right or wrong direction.

    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:44)
 at com.compusoft.synoptixServer.Scheduler.MultiSelect.<init>(MultiSelect.java:17)

Comment: Mate am using intellij in ubuntu, it works fine for me. one thing i could suggest you try to place your geckodriver into a different path

Comment: after moving geckodriver to a new location try this

Comment: ` System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/exeter/Downloads/geckodriver");
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`

Comment: sorry for previous responses  try this code   `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/exeter/Downloads/geckodriver");DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Alright I have tried a new location, but still getting the same error. Is there an issue with the Actions class?
I have tried your code and it does not appear to be working. Still getting the same javanullpointer exception. I wonder if this is an issue specific to a mac? I will try to install an ubuntu vm a bit later and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I just tried this on windows as well and I am still getting the same error. I have some suspicions about my Actions and perhaps I need to post my actual code. I will revise my original question.